# Riemann-Stieltjes Example Clarification

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes, riemann-integration

[image]

I have just been introduced to R-S integrals and I feel I have a basic understanding of the properties, but I am not confident with how to actually apply them. So this may be a stupid question, I am sorry, but to explain where I am getting confused I included an example I was given on how to calculate a simple R-S integral. In the example am I suppose to look at the function dg(s) as: $$x^{2}(t_{i} - t_{i-1})$$
I also dont understand how the constant was derived and I figure once I understand how to set up d(gs) I will be able to figure it out.